# A query regarding sets from Quantum computing since Democritus

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals, well-orders

I was reading the book "Quantum Computing Since Democritus".

> "The set of ordinal numbers has the important property of being well
> ordered,which means that every subset has a minimum element. This is
> unlike the integers or the positive real numbers, where any element
> has another that comes before it."

Unlike integers? Let's consider a set $\{1,2,3\}$ This has a minimum element.

Do you get what does the author wants to say here?

Comment: The author means the set of *all* integers, including the negative integers. And some subsets there, e.g. the negative integers, have no minimal element. The set $\{1,2,3\}$ is, in fact, well-ordered. Not only does it  itself have the minimal element, but any subset of it does too.

Comment: You have exhibited one subset that has a minimum element. But to be well-ordered, *every* subset needs to have a minimum element.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen And can you ever find a subset that does not have a minimum element?

Comment: @Conifold I see. Set of all integers has a minimum $-\inf$?

Comment: @user27286 Sure, the entire set of integers is a subset that has no minimum element.

Comment: Yes, infinite subsets..

Comment: I am a bit stupid

Comment: $-\infty$ isn't an integer, so it can't be the minimal integer.

Comment: *finite* subsets always have a minimum, in any linear order. But not all sets are finite...

Comment: @HennoBrandsma But how does work for ordinals then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integers mean $\Bbb Z$ here, so there we have sets like $\{-1,-2,-3,-4,\ldots\}$ (or $\Bbb Z$ itself) which do not have a minumum element and every $n$ has an element $n-1$ before it. So there are not well-ordered. The positive integers, i.e. $\Bbb N$, are.

Comment: You cant say $-\inf$ is the smallest element because we can find even smaller than that right? But how can you fix it for ordinals? As it starts from 0 we can say 0 is always the minimum?

Comment: $-\infty$ is not a number, so doesn't count. Ordinals start with $0$, the smallest one is $0$ and in any ordinal, $0$ is its minumum element, by construction.

Answer (score 1):

When considering an ordinal $\alpha$ (von neumann ordinals), not all its subsets will have the $0$ as the minimum element. I might be mistaken, but I got the impression that perhaps OP might be assuming that to be the case.

So if one considers $\alpha \subseteq \alpha$, its minimum element will be $0$. In other words $\min(\alpha)=0$.

Now say $\alpha=\omega^3$. We might consider a subset $S_1$ defined as: $S_1=\{\, \omega \cdot (1+x) \,|\, x \in \mathrm{Ord} \, \, \wedge x<\omega^2 \, \}$. Similarly we might define $S_2=\{\,\omega^2 \cdot (1+x) \,|\, x \in \mathrm{Ord} \, \, \wedge x<\omega \, \}$. We can also write $S_2=\{\, \omega^2,\, \omega^2 \cdot 2,\, \omega^2 \cdot 3,.... \,\}$. Both $S_1$ and $S_2$ are well-defined subsets of $\alpha=\omega^3$. However, we have $\min(S_1)=\omega$ and $\min(S_2)=\omega^2$.

**Edit:** An easier example similar to two above. Define $S_0=\{\, 1+x \,|\, x \in \mathrm{Ord} \, \, \wedge x<\omega^3 \, \}$. We get $S_0 \subset \omega^3$ and $\min(S_0)=1$.

Comment: Alright. I see.

Comment: @user27286 One other thing. The definitions I wrote for $S_0$, $S_1$, $S_2$ might be a bit more complicated than necessary. I think a simpler way to write would be: $S_0=\{\, 1+x \,|\, x \in \omega^3 \, \}$,  $S_1=\{\, \omega \cdot (1+x) \,|\, x \in \omega^2  \, \}$ and $S_2=\{\,\omega^2 \cdot (1+x) \,|\, x \in \omega \, \}$.

Comment: Btw what is this $\omega$?

Comment: @user27286 OK I see you are quite new to this. $\omega$ is the "smallest ordinal" which contains an infinite number of elements. It might be helpful to search terms like "ordinal addition" along-side with "ordinal multiplication" and "ordinal arithmetic" etc. ...... both on this site and in general. Generally speaking, it is useful (and not that difficult once you get the hang of it) to be intuitively familiar with ordinals below $\omega^\omega$.

Comment: Perhaps the following link might be useful (to get some idea): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_ordinal. Also $\omega$ is sometimes written as "smallest infinite ordinal".